# ImageCreate() error Size Issue

Tags: php, css

I created images in php to display in my home page

```
ImageCreate(200, 800); // very simple and working. No sizing it is an issue for me.
```

Is there a way to just set the size of this image so that the width of the image always expands to a percentage of the page. eg. If I put 4 images on my page each image will just take up 25% of the page width. I tried to `ImageCreate(25%,100%)` but it does not work.

Comment: When you say page width, do you mean width of the viewport (browser window) or a fixed width you've applied using CSS on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just 4 color blocks with a width of 25%, you could just use 4 divs and set the background color to the one you want and the width to 25%.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the browser viewport width and height with javascript and submit them using AJAX to the image creation script. Have the AJAX return the path to the image and then place the image where you want it on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/makeimage.php',
        data: $.param({
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height()
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#where-your-image-goes').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just extend the Post from Ben

The jQuery Part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/makeimage.php',
        data: $.param({
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height()
        }),
        success: function(data) {
           $('#where-your-image-goes').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

the PHP Part in makeImage.php

```
$oneImageWidth  = intval($_POST['width'] / 4); /* the 25% */
$oneImageHeight = intval($_POST['height']);
ImageCreate(25%,100%);
```

?>

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the input. I feel like I should steal this addition for my answer :)

Comment: ^^ sorry I won´t steal your reputation :)

Comment: No problem :) The whole point of this place is to provide good answers. Mine was lacking.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language so it has no idea of what size the browser is ... you could use CSS and set the image width to a percentage - but this might distort the image if you create it too small .... just out of interest why do you create the images each time you display the page ?

This might help you -> http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

Comment: Hi it's the width of the browser window and a color block i create so distortion is not a issue. So the color blocks expands the entire width of the page 4 colors in total.